# Aliasing a function on a C interface within a C++ application on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, interface, alias

I am compiling a c interface on my library (GCC 4.4.4-14 ubuntu 5.1), which essentially looks like this

header

```
extern "C" 
{
  int foo()
}
```

implementation

```
int foo()
{}

int bar() __attribute__((alias ("foo")));
```

This compiles fine, but when I link the shared object to a test application, and try and call bar(), the function is not recognised.

I tried moving the alias line from implementation to header, and then i get a compiler error:

```
bar() aliased to undefined symbol foo
```

Why does moving the alias to the header, result in this error? and how do i get it all working please?

Comment: Does shared library have symbol `bar` somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from booiljoung's answer above, you might also find the below information from [gcc site](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) useful:

alias ("target")
The alias attribute causes the declaration to be emitted as an alias for another symbol, which must be specified. For instance, 
          void **f () { /* Do something. */; }
          void f () _*attribute*** ((weak, alias ("_f")));

defines `f' to be a weak alias for`_*f'. In C++, the mangled name for the target must be used. **It is an error if `***_f' is not defined in the same translation unit.

Not all target machines support this attribute.

Comment: Thanks Jay, I had seen this documentation. From my understanding, the alias should be fine in the header or implementation as this forms the translation unit. Also, what does it mean by "Not all target machines support this attribute"?

Answer (score 1):

extern "C" needs for implementation.

```
extern "C" 
{
  int foo();
}


extern "C" // <<< extern "C" also!!!
{
  int foo()
  {}
}

int bar() __attribute__((alias ("foo")));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @booiljoung, with your suggested changes my test application has a compile error with:

error: 'bar' was not declared in this scope.

Comment: int bar() is not in a header file, i was not aware that was how the alias worked.

Comment: Jay mean some proccessor not support __attribute__. right? Jay?

Comment: Yes. As I understand it, yes.